# UX for toggling push notifications in iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification

Im working on the settings view for my app’s user specifically on a switch to toggle push notifications.
What would be the correct user experience when turning the switch off in iOS?
a) a boolean in the user class turned o false
b) removing the installation(parse server) with the user token 
c) sending the user to the setting permission and having the user disallow push notifications for the app
d) all of the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't want to do c) since that would prevent them from ever receiving push notifications from you without them re-enabling it from settings.

Similar situation with b); if the installation it will have to be re-added in order to send them notifications.

a) is most likely your best bet. You could create a Cloud Code function that sends pushes to a user and give it a quick `if user["arePushNotificationsEnabled"]` check at the start.

This way you give the user the desired behavior but don't have to make them jump through any hoops to start receiving them again. (Plus you can still send them really important notifications should you need to).